# How is this Jquery behaviour possible in a single-threaded environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, typescript

First, the task: I have a series of validations that need to be done on a server for each keystroke.
This is implemented via AJAX. So the issue that comes up is what if the penultimate (invalid) response is sent by the server after the ultimate (valid) one. Our Javascript code will look like we just sent an invalid response. So I tried to be fancy and implement some sort of queue manager that would expire previous ajax requests, so that they're not processed if they ever return from the server. Here is the code for this (sorry it's in Typescript)

```
class AjaxManager {
    constructor(private options: AjaxOptions) {

    }
    _requests : Array<AjaxObject> = new Array<AjaxObject>();

    send(settings: JQueryAjaxSettings, block : boolean) {
        let request = $.ajax(settings);
        var aO = new AjaxObject(request, settings, block); 
        request.always((data) => {
            this.pruneEarlierRequests(aO);
        });
        this._requests.push(aO);
    }

    private pruneEarlierRequests(ajaxObject: AjaxObject) {
        var requestedIndex = this._requests.findIndex((search) => { return search.id === ajaxObject.id; });

        if ( requestedIndex === -1)
            return; //don't prune if this request doesn't even exist here, probably an error.
        if (this._requests[requestedIndex] == undefined)
            return;
        var data = this._requests[requestedIndex].settings.data.text;
        console.log("pruning " + data);
        for (var index = 0; index < this._requests.length; index++) {
            console.log("processing " + data + ", index: " + index);
            if (this._requests[index].id !== ajaxObject.id) {
                console.log("aborted and pruned " + this._requests[index].settings.data.text + " at index " + index + ", currently processing " + data + " at index " + requestedIndex);
                this._requests[index].request.abort();
            } else {
                console.log("pruned " + this._requests[index].settings.data.text + " at index " + index + ", currently processing " + data + " at index " + requestedIndex);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class AjaxObject {
    id: string;

    constructor(public request: JQueryXHR, public settings : JQueryAjaxSettings, public block : boolean) {
        this.id = this.guid();
    }
    guid() {
        let _p8 = (s = false) : string=> {
            var p = (Math.random().toString(16) + "000000000").substr(2, 8);
            return s ? "-" + p.substr(0, 4) + "-" + p.substr(4, 4) : p;
        }
        return "{" + _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8() + "}";
    }
}
```

The basic idea is that because JS is single-threaded, we'll always initiate send requests in the order that the user types them in. Then when we receive a response from an ajax call, we'll abort all preceding entries.

Now, because I assume (and I may be wrong), given an input of 123, I assume something like the following
We have 5 elements in requests, corresponding to 1,12,123
Then:

pruning 12 (it arrived before 1)
aborted and pruned 1
pruned 12

pruning 1
pruned 1

pruning 123
aborted and pruned 1
aborted and pruned 12
pruned 123

Instead, and this is the problem, I'm getting output that seems to indicate that these promises are handled on different threads (I removed some of the entries)

> pruning vancouve
>
> processing vancouve, index: 0
>
> aborted and pruned  at index 0, currently processing
>   vancouve at index 8
>
> processing vancouve, index: 1
>
> aborted and pruned v at index 1, currently processing vancouve at
>   index 8
>
> processing vancouve, index: 2
>
> aborted and pruned va at index 2, currently processing vancouve at
>   index 8
>
> processing vancouve, index: 3
>
> aborted and pruned van at index 3, currently processing vancouve at
>   index 8
>
> processing vancouve, index: 4
>
> aborted and pruned vanc at index 4, currently processing vancouve at
>   index 8
>
> processing vancouve, index: 5
>
> aborted and pruned vanco at index 5, currently processing vancouve at
>   index 8
>
> processing vancouve, index: 6
>
> aborted and pruned vancou at index 6, currently processing vancouve at
>   index 8
>
> pruning vancou
>
> processing vancou, index: 0
>
> aborted and pruned  at index 0, currently processing
>   vancou at index 6
>
> processing vancou, index: 1
>
> aborted and pruned v at index 1, currently processing vancou at index
>   6
>
> processing vancou, index: 2
>
> aborted and pruned va at index 2, currently processing vancou at index
>   6
>
> processing vancou, index: 3
>
> aborted and pruned van at index 3, currently processing vancou at
>   index 6
>
> processing vancou, index: 4
>
> aborted and pruned vanc at index 4, currently processing vancou at
>   index 6
>
> processing vancou, index: 5
>
> aborted and pruned vanco at index 5, currently processing vancou at
>   index 6
>
> processing vancou, index: 6
>
> pruned vancou at index 6, currently processing vancou at index 6
>
> processing vancouve, index: 7
>
> aborted and pruned vancouv at index 7, currently processing vancouve
>   at index 8
>
> pruning vancouv
>
> processing vancouv, index: 0
>
> aborted and pruned  at index 0, currently processing
>   vancouv at index 7
>
> processing vancouv, index: 1
>
> aborted and pruned v at index 1, currently processing vancouv at index
>   7
>
> processing vancouv, index: 2
>
> aborted and pruned va at index 2, currently processing vancouv at
>   index 7
>
> processing vancouv, index: 3
>
> aborted and pruned van at index 3, currently processing vancouv at
>   index 7
>
> processing vancouv, index: 4
>
> aborted and pruned vanc at index 4, currently processing vancouv at
>   index 7
>
> processing vancouv, index: 5
>
> aborted and pruned vanco at index 5, currently processing vancouv at
>   index 7
>
> processing vancouv, index: 6
>
> aborted and pruned vancou at index 6, currently processing vancouv at
>   index 7
>
> processing vancouv, index: 7
>
> pruned vancouv at index 7, currently processing vancouv at index 7
>
> processing vancouve, index: 8
>
> pruned vancouve at index 8, currently processing vancouve at index 8

Completely as a surprise to me, halfway through processing the response at index 8 (vancouve), it went and handled the response for index 6 and index 7. Now, I expect that 8 would arrive before 6 and 7, but I would assume that the processing would be fully finished for 8 before the processing for 6 and 7 would start.  My question then, is why is this happening, and how do I make sure that the processing for each response is fully complete?

I contemplated whether this is just a property of console.log, but the processing order is actually affecting the logic (sometimes later requests are canceled by earlier requests).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded, however, there are some actions that occur on a different thread, such as http requests in your case. HTTP requests will be sent in order, but there is no guarantee that they will be responded to in order.

Comment: @KevinB So I understand that the request is happening on a different thread, but I assumed that the handling of the responses all happened on the same thread (ie, as requests came back from the server, the callbacks are all put on the queue to be executed in a single thread). Am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: No, you're correct, what you're missing is that they aren't inserted into the callback queue in the order they are sent; they are inserted into the callback queue in the order that they complete.

Comment: For example, if you call setTimeout 3 times, each time with a decreasing duration, they will *complete* in the opposite order that you begin them. The same can occur with http requests.

Comment: In your case, it looks like you are building an autocomplete or similar tool. On the first keystroke, the value is 'a'. so it searches the database for all results that match 'a'. On second keystroke, it searches for 'ap', which will return *less* results than the first, and therefore very well could finish before the first does.

Comment: @KevinB Right, which I accounted for. What I'm having issue with is that they are being inserted mid function. In my example above, based on that for loop, I expect that nothing will interrupt index 8 until the function finishes. Yet half way through I see index 6, and some of index 7 process, only for the last index 8 call to come in. But all of index 8 is handled in the same loop! To me, this looks like `pruneEarlierRequests` is called concurrently, and 6 is running at the same time as 8 and 7

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, nothing can interrupt a for loop (well, other than a return), they're synchronous.

Comment: All your for loop is doing is aborting requests. Keep in mind, the `always` callback on all of those aborted requests will then fire.

Comment: Which is what I'm demonstrating above. I have console.log return lines that end with `currently processing vancouve at index 8`. All of those are coming from the same loop. That 8 is from a variable calculated at the beginning of `pruneEarlierRequests`. Now look at the order in which the logs are returned in the yellow quote. it's 8,8,8,8,8,8,6,6,6,6,6,6,8. How did all those 6's get called `in the middle` of the loop that was handling the 8?

Comment: hehe, for each aborted request, pruneEarlierRequests is being called again.

Comment: @KevinB Yup, agreed. But each aborted request is a number, specifically, so in the previous comment, 8 was the 8th request, 6 is the 6th request, etc. In the call for that request, we abort all previous requests (in my previous code, I also removed them from the queue, but I removed that during debugging).  But each loop is just 1 call.  Which doesn't answer how the 6's, which are all ONE call of pruneEarlierRequests get in the middle of the 8's, which are ANOTHER ONE call of pruneEarlierRequests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164211/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-kolichikov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, it seems that `.abort` causes the `.always` callback to be called synchronously, which causes a new loop to begin in the middle of processing the original loop. A quick fix for this would be to do anything that would push that call to `.abort`, or, the call to `pruneAbortedRequests` to the callback queue so that it won't be called until the previous function is done running.

For example, wrapping it in a setTimeout.

```
request.always((data) => {
    setTimeout(() => this.pruneEarlierRequests(aO), 0);
});
```

I don't immediately see a better solution than something like this, other than not aborting requests and using a different technique to reduce the number of requests.